# Google places api in android not working 404 error

Tags: android, google-maps

iam developing an android app in which iam getting a places name the problem is when i give URL i always get response 404 was not found on server,i think my URL query is not correct can any one help me

```
String place=s.toString();
            String apiKey="*****key******";
            final String url= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/json?  key="+apiKey+"&input="+place;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you got this call from? The places API usually starts with https and contains an action after /place so i.e. /place/nearbysearch
Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search